# resource not appearing in New Server Window

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I am using eclipse Indigo, In project explorer I can see my project there. I want to add server to my project so that I can run/test my web application.

After creating new server of type Tomcat > Tomcat 6. A window appear to add/move resource (my project) to right window so that new server configured with my project. But that window is empty. How I can show my project in left window?
[image]

following Project Facets installed
[image]

Comment: after creating server try running your web-app on server by selecting "Run on server"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be absolutely sure that your project has Web Project Facet enabled. You can enable facets in project properties. Normally the facet you are looking for is called **Dynamic Web Module**.

[image]

Comment: I have following facet enabled, Java, Javascript, jst.Web. (Static Web Module - Unchecked). In bottom there is a warning 'Implementation of project facet jst.web could not be found, functionality will be limited'

Comment: What type of Eclipse is that (i.e Classic, EE edition)? What have you chosen when you were creating this project in the "New Project" Window?

Comment: @coure2011 My Project Facets looks like yours did in your screen shots. How did you get the extra options to make this solution work? I originally downloaded Eclipse Java but I am in the Java EE perspective.

Answer (score 4):

I Encounter your situation when starting out with a new install of 'Eclipse Standard'.

You have to install some additional software:
(help->install new software) search "--all avaiable sites--" search for "Web"
and install **"Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development"**. 
That will allow you to setup your Project Poperties -> Project Facelets -> "Dynamic Web Module"

Comment: There are many items available under Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development. Which one are you referring to?

Comment: Thank you. I was not able to find this exactly, but this works using the Marketplace and installing EE Tools.